# How to make dictionary of 1st and 4th column of the table in the txt file here:

Tags: python, file, dictionary

ID  Name    Work    Rate    Friends\n

```html
ID Name Work Rate Friends \n
123 John Writer 15 34 \n
124 Greene Doctor 53 76 \n
125 Stephen Jobless 86 86 \n
126 King Doctor 24 14 \n
127 Sal Writer 68 98 \n
128 Harp Teacher 57 4 \n
129 Lee Pilot 48 2 \n
130 Ted Labor 96 68 \n
131 Zusak Doctor 85 98 \n
132 Mark Jobless 35 24 \n
133 Twain Jobless 75 98 \n
```

123 John    Writer  15  34
124 Greene  Doctor  53  76
125 Stephen Jobless 86  86
126 King    Doctor  24  14
127 Sal Writer  68  98
128 Harp    Teacher 57  4
129 Lee Pilot   48  2
130 Ted Labor   96  68
131 Zusak   Doctor  85  98
132 Mark    Jobless 35  24
133 Twain   Jobless 75  98

Comment: What did you try and why did it not work? Possibly related: please take the [tour] and visit the [Help] to check how to ask a good question on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some thoughts.

But first, note the following:

- I converted your text file into a comma-separated-values(csv) file.
- I am not 100% sure of your desire output, so I made some assumptions.
- If you must solve this using a .txt file, reply with an example of what your file looks like; when I copy the example you provided, in addition to \n, I get more chars that may or may not be unintentional (i.e \t).

Here is what your data looks like as a csv locally.

| ID | Name | Work | Rate | Friends |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | John | Writer | 15 | 34 |
| 124 | Greene | Doctor | 53 | 76 |
| 125 | Stephen | Jobless | 86 | 86 |
| 126 | King | Doctor | 24 | 14 |
| 127 | Sal | Writer | 68 | 98 |
| 128 | Harp | Teacher | 57 | 4 |
| 129 | Lee | Pilot | 48 | 2 |
| 130 | Ted | Labor | 96 | 68 |
| 131 | Zusak | Doctor | 85 | 98 |
| 132 | Mark | Jobless | 35 | 24 |
| 133 | Twain | Jobless | 75 | 98 |

Assuming you wish to save IDs and Rate...
Here is the code

```
import csv  # module which makes it easy to work with csv files. 
from pathlib import Path  # module to work with paths. Provides reach support for file creating as well
from collections import namedtuple  # subclass of tuple, allows for fields to be named


file_path = Path.joinpath(Path.cwd(), 'data_.csv')  # represents the location for the file with the data
Record = namedtuple('Record', ['ID', 'Rate'])  # creates a represenation of what a record should look like

with file_path.open(mode="r", encoding="utf-8") as file:  # open file with an 'with' statement so that file closes when going out of scope
  reader = csv.DictReader(file)  # uses a DictReader class-instance to manage the file
  fields = {'ID': [], 'Rate': []}  # an idea on how to represent your data. => {ID: [1, 2, 3,...], Rate: [10.00, 20.00,...]}
                                   # I don't like this because the association between ID and Rates is lost. 
                                   # Especially if at any moment fields['ID'] or fields['Rate'] changes.
  list = []  # another idea on how to store your data. Example: [(Id, Rate), (Id, Rate), (Id, Rate)]. 
                  # I like this because the relationship between Ids and Rates are kept

  for row in reader:  # use the reader obj to iterate through each line
    id, *_, rate, _ = row.values()  # grab the values for each row and unpack them, only grabbing what we need
    #saving to fields
    fields["ID"].append(id)
    fields["Rate"].append(rate)
    #saving to our list
    list.append(Record(id, rate))
    
  print(fields)
  print(list)
```

If you are going to consume these values right away, you should look into list comprehension to make your code memory efficient.

Once again, just some thoughts

Comment: note: 
you can cast the reader instance into a list and get a list of all lines, this may be helpful as well.

Answer (score -1):

read the text in to array

```
text_file = open("yourfile.txt", "r")
data = text_file.read().splitlines()
for i in range(len(lines)):
    data[i] = data[i].strip('\n').split('\t')
```

you can take the required into dict

```
 for i in range(1, len(data)):
      my_dict[i]={"id":data[0][0], "rate":data[0][3]}
```